# javac: directory not found: bin Usage: javac <options> <source files> ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

```
javac: directory not found: bin
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

when i try to run

```
javac -sourcepath src Downloads//Runner.java -d bin
```

i get error.

those are my paths

```
  vegan@vegan:~$ echo $PATH
/home/vegan/bin:/home/vegan/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin
vegan@vegan:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
vegan@vegan:~$
```

because in doc it says

```
ACME has a utility which generates audit reports - lists of files owned by
```

users. Substitute JAVA_HOME with your JVM installation and you can build & run
the utility like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac -sourcepath src src/com/reengen/utils/auditreporter/Runner.java -d bin
```

Comment: [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) ___clearly___ says that the directory from the "-d" option must exist and will not be created by `javac`, so what exactly is unclear here?

Comment: in my doc it says $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac -sourcepath src src/com/reengen/utils/auditreporter/Runner.java -d bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the `bin` directory first. Run `mkdir bin` and try again.

Comment: i have bin? vegan@vegan:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin$ ls
appletviewer  javac           javaws    jinfo       jsadebugd     orbd         serialver
ControlPanel  javadoc         jcmd      jjs         jstack        pack200      servertool
extcheck      javafxpackager  jconsole  jmap        jstat         policytool   tnameserv
idlj          javah           jcontrol  jmc         jstatd        rmic         unpack200
jar           javap           jdb       jmc.ini     jvisualvm     rmid         
java          java-rmi.cgi    jhat      jrunscript  native2ascii  schemagen    xjc

Comment: @mark You are compiling in `$HOME` (`/home/vegan`) with source in `$HOME/src` (`/home/vegan/src`) and targeting `$HOME/bin` (which does not exist). `mkdir $HOME/bin`

Comment: Because the directory did not exist before, and `javac` will not create it.